# Shortest path algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, shortest-path

I'm struggling with an algorithm that is pretty basic at its core. I have an array filled with:

```
O- path
X- wall
*-main hero
W-exits
```

I have a problem, because I have created an array that should keep branched paths, that later in the program, I can analyze again. If we have three different paths, the algorithm should first go down, then right, left and lastly up. If the exit is found, the program should check if other paths lead to the exit, and if so, compare counters (`licznik`). But after one run, the program won't go check other paths from my array. Any ideas what's wrong?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void display(int wiersze, int kolumny, string** labirynth)
{
    //system("cls");
for(int i = 0 ; i<wiersze; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<kolumny; ++j)
    {
        cout << "[" <<labirynth[i][j]<<"]";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

int main()
{
      int wiersze,kolumny,startkol,startwier,exits,X,Y;
wiersze=8;
string** labirynth = new string* [wiersze];
//tworzy labirynt
for(int i = 0; i<wiersze; ++i)
{
    labirynth[i]= new string[kolumny];
}
//wypelnia brzegi
for(int i = 0 ; i<wiersze; ++i)
{

    for(int j = 0; j<kolumny; ++j)
    {
        if(i==0 || j==0 || i==wiersze-1 || j==kolumny-1)
        {
            labirynth[i][j]="X";
        }
        else
        {
            labirynth[i][j]=" ";
        }

    }
}
display(wiersze,kolumny,labirynth);
/*/
cout<<"Podaj punkt startowy X."<<endl;
cin >>startkol;
cout<<"Podaj punkt startowy Y."<<endl;
cin >> startwier;
/*/
startkol=4;
startwier=1;
labirynth[startwier-1][startkol-1]="*";

display(wiersze,kolumny,labirynth);
/*/
    cout<< "Podaj ilosc wyjsc." <<endl;
    cin >> exits;
    int exitX, exitY;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<exits; i++)
    {
        cout << "Podaj X wyjscia nr. " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> X;
        cout << "Podaj Y wyjscia nr. " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> Y;
        labirynth[Y-1][X-1]="W";
        exitX = X-1;
        exitY = Y-1;

        display(wiersze,kolumny,labirynth);
    }
    /*/
/////////////////////////ustawiam wyjscie i sciezki
labirynth[7][5]="W";
labirynth[1][3]="O";
labirynth[2][3]="O";
labirynth[2][2]="O";
labirynth[2][1]="O";
labirynth[2][0]="W";
labirynth[3][3]="O";
labirynth[5][3]="O";
labirynth[4][3]="O";
labirynth[4][4]="O";
labirynth[4][5]="O";
labirynth[5][5]="O";
labirynth[6][5]="O";

display(wiersze,kolumny,labirynth);
////////////////////////
/*/
for(;;)
{
    cout << "Podaj X sciezki" <<endl;
    cin>>X;
    if(X==0)
    {
        break;
    }
    cout << "Podaj Y sciezki" << endl;
    cin >> Y;
    labirynth[Y-1][X-1]="O";
    display(wiersze,kolumny,labirynth);

}
/*/
//filler
for(int i = 0 ; i<wiersze; ++i)
{

    for(int j = 0; j<kolumny; ++j)
    {
        if(labirynth[i][j]==" ")
        {
            labirynth[i][j]="X";
        }

    }
}


int licznik=0;
int sk=startkol-1;
int sw=startwier-1;
bool spr[4];
spr[0] = false;
int pom[3][100];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
    {
        pom[i][j]=0; //sets pom to 0

    }
}
int counter = 0;
while(sw+1<wiersze && sk+1<kolumny)
{


    if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="O")
    {
        spr[0] = true;

        labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
        sw += 1;
        cout<<"->Down";
        if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
        {
            labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
            cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(labirynth[sw][sk-1]=="O" && spr[0])
    {
        pom[0][counter] = sk - 1;
        pom[1][counter] = sw;
        pom[2][counter] = licznik;
        counter++;
        if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
        {
            labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
            cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(labirynth[sw][sk-1]=="O" && !spr[0])
    {
        labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
        sk -= 1;
        cout<<"->Left";
        if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
        {
            labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
            cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(labirynth[sw][sk+1]=="O" && spr[0])
    {
        pom[0][counter] = sk + 1;
        pom[1][counter] = sw;
        pom[2][counter] = licznik;

        counter++;
        if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
        {
            labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
            cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(labirynth[sw][sk+1]=="O" && !spr[0] )
    {
        labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
        sk += 1;
        cout<<"->Right";
        if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
        {
            labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
            cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(labirynth[sw-1][sk]=="O" && spr[0])
    {
        pom[0][counter] = sk;
        pom[1][counter] = sw - 1;
        pom[2][counter] = licznik;
        counter++;
        if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
        {
            labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
            cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(labirynth[sw-1][sk]=="O" && !spr[0])
    {
        labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
        sw -= 1;
        cout<<"->Up";
        if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
        {
            labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
            cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    spr[0] = false;
    if(labirynth[sw-1][sk]!="O" && labirynth[sw+1][sk]!="O" && labirynth[sw][sk+1]!="O" && labirynth[sw][sk-1]!="O")
    {
        cout<<endl<<"NO EXITS FOUND"<<endl;
        break;
    }
}
display(wiersze,kolumny,labirynth);
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
    {
        if(pom[i][j]==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        cout<<pom[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int i =0;


for(;;)
{
    sw=pom[0][i];
    sk=pom[1][i];

    if(pom[0][i]==0 && pom[1][i]==0 && pom[2][i]==0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {

        while(sw+1<wiersze && sk+1<kolumny)
        {


            if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="O")
            {
                spr[0] = true;

                labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                sw += 1;
                cout<<"->Down";
                if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
                {
                    labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                    cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(labirynth[sw][sk-1]=="O" && spr[0])
            {
                pom[0][counter] = sk - 1;
                pom[1][counter] = sw;
                pom[2][counter] = licznik;
                counter++;
                if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
                {
                    labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                    cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(labirynth[sw][sk-1]=="O" && !spr[0])
            {
                labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                sk -= 1;
                cout<<"->Left";
                if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
                {
                    labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                    cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(labirynth[sw][sk+1]=="O" && spr[0])
            {
                pom[0][counter] = sk + 1;
                pom[1][counter] = sw;
                pom[2][counter] = licznik;

                counter++;
                if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
                {
                    labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                    cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(labirynth[sw][sk+1]=="O" && !spr[0] )
            {
                labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                sk += 1;
                cout<<"->Right";
                if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
                {
                    labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                    cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(labirynth[sw-1][sk]=="O" && spr[0])
            {
                pom[0][counter] = sk;
                pom[1][counter] = sw - 1;
                pom[2][counter] = licznik;
                counter++;
                if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
                {
                    labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                    cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(labirynth[sw-1][sk]=="O" && !spr[0])
            {
                labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                sw -= 1;
                cout<<"->UP";
                if(labirynth[sw+1][sk]=="W")
                {
                    labirynth[sw][sk] = "%";
                    cout<<endl<<"EXIT FOUND on: ["<<sw+2<<"]["<<sk+1<<"]"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            spr[0] = false;
            if(labirynth[sw-1][sk]!="O" && labirynth[sw+1][sk]!="O" && labirynth[sw][sk+1]!="O" && labirynth[sw][sk-1]!="O")
            {
                cout<<endl<<"NO EXITS FOUND"<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }




    }
    i++;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [mcve please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code would be easier to read with correct indentations.